# How to make onkeyup works in next row?How to make Javascript works in next row?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I Make CRUD with Php and success.
as usual for show data PHP use while looping.
In the Edit action I used Popup/Modal didn't make a new page for edit, actually my Edit was running smoothly.

But I have a problem with JavaScript for function automatically, when one form/field is filled, the other form/field is filled (actually only one field is automatic).**this automatic problem only works on the first row edit action (works smoothly) but on the next row automatically does not work**

Javascript doesn't work in while looping, it only works on the first loop, the next loop doesn't work.

I have done various automation methods with Javascript but the results are the same, only Edit the first row, the next row doesn't work. did I do something wrong?

**CODE JS(Javascript)**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   function Sremarks() {
      if ($('#result').val() != 0) {
         var input = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value);
         var result = parseInt(document.getElementById('result').value);
         if(input < result){
            document.getElementById('remarks').value = "bad";
         }else{
            document.getElementById('remarks').value = "Good";
         }
      } else{
            document.getElementById('remarks').value = "0";
     }
   }
</script>
```

**CODE PHP and HTML**

here I am using onkeyup = "Sremarks ()" to pass to Function Js like in line Form/Field Edit Input and result

```
<form action="editmhs.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!-- Open Php While Looping -->
  <?php
  $id = $pecah['id']; 
  $query_edit = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM axle1 WHERE id='$id'");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_edit)) {  
  ?>

  <!-- Form/Field Id hidden -->
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">

  <!-- Form/Field Edit Input -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Input</label>
    <input type="number" name="input" id="input" class="form-control" min="0" max="100" value="<?php echo $row['input']; ?>" onkeyup="Sremarks()">      
  </div>

  <!-- Form/Field Edit Result -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Result</label>
    <input type="number" name="result" id="result" class="form-control" min="0" max="100" value="<?php echo $row['result']; ?>" onkeyup="Sremarks()">      
  </div>

  <!-- Form/Field Edit Remarks -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Remarks</label>
    <input type="text" name="remarks" id="remarks" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['remarks']; ?>" readonly>      
  </div>

  <!-- Button submit and Close -->
  <div class="modal-footer">  
    <button type="submit" name="upload_ubah" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Close PHP While Looping -->
  <?php 
  }
  ?>        
</form>
```

Comment: You can not have multiple elements with the same id. That's why it works only for the first input.

Comment: did you resolve this ?

Comment: yapp I can solve it